# Undertow: Using existing Servlet instance

Tags: java, servlets, undertow

I am trying to replace in an existing application the embedded web server with Undertow as the old does not work correctly in some cases.

The embedded web server is used to server a few simple servlets. My main problem is that I can't find a way to register an existing `HttpServlet` instance in Undertow.

All API methods I was able to find only accept an `Class<? extends Servlet>`. Also the [servlet tutorials](https://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.1.0/index.html#creating-a-servlet-deployment) and others only use `Class<? extends Servlet>` for registering a servlet.

My Servlets however already exists and I need to use them directly as each servlet is already configured with certain parameters and thus can not be created by just providing a class name.

Is there any way to use an existing instance of a class that implements `javax.servlet.Servlet` directly in Undertow or is Undertow not usable for such a case?

Comment: @BalusC Do you have any reference where that is stated? For traditional web server it may make sense as you have to reference the Servlet class in the config file, but a server designed to be embedded into an app this does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @BalusC I even found this definition in Servlet 2.1 spec (available in Wayback Machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use an existing `Servlet` instance in Undertow by using the method `Servlet.servlet(String, Class<? extends Servlet>, InstanceFactory<? extends Servlet> servlet)`:

```
Servlet myServletInstance = ...
Servlets.servlet("MessageServlet", MessageServlet.class, 
    new ImmediateInstanceFactory<Servlet>(myServletInstance))
            .addMapping("/*")
```

In this case the class parameter is ignored and instead of creating a new instance via constructor by Undertow internally, the provided servlet instance is used.